# OneDrive for business API : Can not share file

Tags: sharepoint-api, onedrive

I have used OneDrive API to upload and get shared (embed) link:

```
POST /drive/items/{item-id}/action.createLink
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {access token}
{
  "type": "view"
}
```

And received file with link that could be visible for everyone like "`https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=5D33DD65C6932946!70859&authkey=!AL7N1QAfSWcjNU8&ithint=folder%2cgif`"

But now i am trying to use OneDrive for business API:

```
POST https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drive/items/{file-id}/action.createLink
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {access token}
{
  "type": "view"
}
```

And it returns

```
   401 Unauthorized

   error: {
            code: "unauthenticated"
            message: "The caller is not authenticated."
          }
```

Also i have searched for this functionality on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/files-rest-operations#Fileoperations for v1.0 business API, but there is **nothing about sharing files** at all.

P.S: All operations related to **getting metadata, uploading file, removing file** is working on both API versions for "OneDrive for business".

I am wondering if using of OneDrive will even help me to store some file and getting public embed link for it...

P.P.S: i am using HttpClient object to work with native REST API, but i don`t think that problem is on my side...

Comment: Its working now, seems like there was some problems on API side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working now, seems like there was some problems on API side